# How to retain the background color when i hover to sibling using CSS

Tags: css, background, hover

I have build a dropdown menu that works a sweet as it gets.
Right click on an element, brings up he dropdown menu, i hover over the first choise, soo far so good, the font color and the background color changes as it should and the sub-menue opens. The problem is that when i hover over the sub-menu, the i "loose" the gray background color of the "parent"
Any ideas ?

```
<div id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="display: block; left: 997px; top: 438px;">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu side" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;"><li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paste" aria-hidden="true"></i> PARENT OPTION</a> <ul class="dropdown-menu"> <li> <a tabindex="-1" data-url="/common/docitem/copymove/?document=247&amp;dest=1&amp;obj_table=companydocument&amp;f=null" id="add_id_copy_p" style="cursor:pointer;" class="js-movecopy-docitem"> Siblin Option</a> </li>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Your code does not show us a vital bit - what you are doing on hover. Please make a working snippet showing how far you have got so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you must include a code segment to make it easier to understand the issue, as @Paulie-d and @Rokibol Hasan mentioned. To be honest, this sounds like maybe you have conflicting CSS rules or lack of specificity, which results in your parent element being affected on :hover.

These would be the steps I would use to solve this:

1. Use the find function of your development IDE (CTRL + F) to find :hover elements. Avoid using very broad CSS selectors.
2. Make sure you have assigned the correct `id` and `class` attributes in the desired section of code.
3. Refresh your memory on CSS [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp). I provide you this website instead of Mozilla only because I do not know if you can handle it. If you are experienced, [prefer this website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
4. Refresh your memory on CSS [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).
5. At this point, go in your CSS and start commenting out and testing one by one sections of code that may affect the parent element you speak of.